# How to use sql transaction in multiple efcontexts and multi-thread in ef core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactionscope

Let's say I have 10 methods that will run in parallel. In each of them, I am creating a DbContext and making changes in the database. I CANNOT use one instance of DbContext, because every method will do a huge update and it will not be efficient. My code is like this:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(Method1);
var task2 = Task.Run(Method2);
var task3 = Task.Run(Method3);
var task10 = Task.Run(Method10);


Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3, task10);

void Method1()
{
    using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
        //Huge update
    }
}

void Method2()
{
    using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
        //Huge update
    }
}

void Method3()
{
    using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
        //Huge update
    }
}

void Method10()
{
    using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
        //huge update
    }
}


class MyContext : DbContext
{

}
```

The problem that I am trying to solve is:

When any of **Method1, Method2 ... Method9** fails, changes of **Method1, Method2 ... Method9** should not be saved, but it should save changes of **Method10**

I read something about **TransactionScope**, but it looks like when we don't commit it, changes of **Method10** will not be saved. What is the proper way of implementing it?

Comment: if you create Dbcontext 1-9 inside TransactionScope and create DbContext10 outside a TransactionScope not solved your problem?

Comment: @MahdiAnjam Can you show any example? Does it work when methods run in paraller?

Comment: Why do you want *any* of this? A DbContext isn't a connection, it's a Unit-of-Work. It *doesn't* need to be transaction safe, it's not doing anything. A single call to `SaveChangesAsync` will store all pending changes in a single internal transaction

Comment: What is `Huge update`? That's what matters. If you load 1M rows only to save them back, you're doing it wrong. EF is an ORM, it's meant to give the impression of working with in-memory objects. It's *not* an ETL tool, alternative to ADO.NET or embedded SQL. If you want to modify multiple rows at once, use an `UPDATE` query. If you want to load changes, load the new rows into a staging table and UPDATE the target

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not saying DbContext is a connection. Huge update means: I am changing 500 entities per method. Except EF Core codes like Get and SaveChanges, I had a lot of BL code there.. I cannot use ADO.NET or SQL since everything is depends on events and will not fit BL code. This is just a legacy code and scenario that I faced with

Comment: The comment is unclear. You're already using ADO.NET and SQL. EF is an ORM, not a database driver. It generates SQL which it executes through the ADO.NET provider you defined. 500 rows is very little data but `everything is depends on events and will not fit BL code.` means the entire code is wrong. ORMs aren't ETL tools. There are no objects in an import/ETL job or rather, the objects are Table, Row, Transformation, not Product, Order

Comment: And even so, 500 objects are *not a lot*. You can load the 500 objects, modify them then call `SaveChanges` just once to save them. What is the code doing? Why are there 10 methods?

Comment: `like Get` there's no `Get` in EF. There's only `Find` which loads objects by their PK values or LINQ queries that load multiple objects. If you use `Find` or `SingelAsync` to load objects one by one instead of all at once, you're doing it wrong. The code will be *at least* 500 times slower than loading all 500 items at once. That's because you execute the load query 500 times instead of once, and saving 500 times instead of once.

Comment: A DbContext handles multiple entities too, which means you can load all the objects you need in a single method, instead of using a separate method for each type. If that's slow, it's because the entire design is wrong (again, using an ORM for ETL work). You won't fix that by trying to run more inappropriate jobs at the same time. If anything, you'll end up causing blocks between the connections used by each DbContext.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I cannot provide full code to make it understandable for you. This is a problem, that I am trying to resolve. Again, this is a legacy code. The solution cannot be re-designing everything

Comment: I've encountered and fixed such problems countless times in the last 20+ years (data warehouses, millions of rows and GBs). It's not me that needs to understand the problem. To find a workaround you *need* to describe the actual problem and post more code so people can tell you what to change. Right now you posted your assumed solution which simply won't work. What's the *actual* problem that made you look at concurrent EF operations? 500 is *no data*, not just little data

Comment: This seems like a case of [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There's a problem X (the entire operation is too slow) and the assumed solution is Y (do more of it in parallel). When that fails (perhaps because the problem is caused by *database blocking*, not CPU), a question is posted about the assumed solution Y, not the real problem X.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254377/discussion-between-dilshod-k-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: There's no reason. Explain what the problem is in the question itself. If you want an answer to your *exact* question, go ahead and create a TransactionScope that wraps all the contexts and commit at the end. This will force EF to keep the connections open for as long as the entire transaction is active, escalate individual SaveChanges transactions into distributed ones and keep any locks generated until you either commit the TransactionScope or dispose it. The concurrent connections could block each other, eg one trying to update the rows already loaded (and share-locked) by the other

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Project is ERP, this code is from its Framework. It has documentation that has more than 100 pages. That's why I can't explain everything. I just make it simple and explainable to others. I just want a solution for this problem. You just mentioned that using TransactionScope is completely wrong and also giving solution with TransactionScope. Can you provide code example?

Comment: Doesn't change the facts. There's no reason to include 100 pages. This is nothing new and ERPs are known for some very bad data practices covered up by claims of "lots of data" of 5 or 50K rows. With SQL Server 1M rows is barely enough for a single delta bucket in a columnstore index. I've worked on such ERPs and CRMs, trying to persuade people to *stop* bad practices, getting 100, 1000, 1K speedups as a result.

Comment: I'm telling you *if you want to shoot yourself in the foot*, go ahead and wrap the tasks and `await` with `using(var tx=new TransactionScope()){var tasks=new[]{ Task.Run(Method1), Task.Run(Method2),...};  await TaskWhenAll(thetasks); tx.Complete();}`. Observe SQL  Server's Activity Monitor while this runs, to see how many connections are used, for how long, and which blocks which. Except to find problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This will not work. This will undo changes of Method20. If it is an answer can you post in as answer, not comment?

Comment: You didn't like the answer. I posted the code for the exact thing you asked and no, it won't undo anything. Why would *committing* a transaction undo changes? There's no `Method20` in the code you posted anyway.

Comment: You can read about transaction handling in EF in [Using Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#using-systemtransactions). Using a transaction scope is shown in [Using System.Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#using-systemtransactions). None of the other options will work (cross-context transactions, explicit transactions) as you want a different connection for each context

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you, I've never heard about Microsoft documentation

Answer (score -1):

```
using  (var dbContext10= new DbContext())   
     { 
       using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
          {
                using (var dbContext1= new DbContext())
                {
                    using (var dbContext2= new DbContext())
                    {
                        //send context to your methods
                        //wait to all tasks after saveChanges
                    }
                }
          }
     }
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. A DbContext isn't a database connection and doesn't need an explicit transaction. There's no connection at all until a query runs or SaveChanges is called. Even then, an internal transaction is called to save *all* pending changes